# Build.gradle: Failed to resolve: com.android.support

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to build my Android Studio project, but I keep getting this "Failed to resolve: com.android.support" error.

This is how the build.gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.training.linus.trainingapp"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.exercise_card.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.exercise_card:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.exercise_card.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

And the other gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I can't figure out why I can't build properly, I have the correct SDK version downloaded and everything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm running 3.1.3

Comment: Removing
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.exercise_card:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.exercise_card.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
Seems to have fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.exercise_card:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.exercise_card.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Seems to have solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Will You show me the error to know problem decently?
generally, the integration problem occur if you update your studio
reinstall the studio and connect with SDK 
you should check 
 dependency in android studio

```
'dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.exercise_card:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.exercise_card.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}'

Comment: https://gyazo.com/6cfb7b547d17edc30598f42d15bd8d5c
There is an image of the error, it doesn't really tell me that much to be honest

Comment: which version you are  using of gradle?

Comment: Gradle version: 4.4

Answer (score 0):

you need to add in the project level gradle in allprojects

```
 maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }


 allprojects {
  repositories {
     jcenter()
      maven {
         url "https://maven.google.com"
      }
      google()
    }
  }
```